# mysql database innodb myisam performance

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam

what are the main technical reasons to use `innodb` type of tables most of the time, rather than `myiasm`.
I searched for it, but not satisfied / confused.
some are saying it depends on the requirement.
can anyone explain how it depends on the requirement and where it differs in performance?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb

Comment: @Rupam - the question you linked is outdated at this point, InnoDB has caught up with missing features present in MyISAM. The main reason you want to use InnoDB is because it's a transactional engine. If you don't know why that's important, you have some googling to do (google for transactions in databases).

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole wikipedia page just for this discussion :-)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_MySQL_database_engines

Comment: Thank you @Leo. I visited the above link but cant get last two columns exactly i.e. Transactional & Under active development, will you please explore that

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB is a right choice if you are using MySQL v5.6 as InnoDB supports full text search (FTS)

You can refer my existing answer from here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam/46663#46663